# What is the difference between /_layouts/usagedetails.aspx and /_layouts/WebAnalytics/Reports.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-analytics

I've been reading about web analytics for SharePoint Online and everything I have read says to refer to https://[site]/_layouts/usagedetails.aspx. When I go there, I get the following message:

```
Usage logging is disabled in this farm. Please contact your farm administrator for more details.
```

But when I when I click on the Site Web Analytics link from Site Settings, I takes me to https://[site]/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=SummaryReport&l=s which actually does give me data.

So it seems to me that usage logging is not disables as the first link says. I'm curious what the difference between these two links is. Is usagedetails.aspx perhaps a deprecated version of WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?

Comment: @thatguyyouknow..I am also facing the same issue,however navigating to [Summary Report] gives me error message as well.Have you done any changes in configuraion for result to Appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UsageDetails.aspx is aimed at SharePoint Foundation and is much more basic than Web Analytics (which is available in SharePoint Server 2010 Standard / Enterprise).  If you have SharePoint Server, you should be using the Analytics, not the Usage Details.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if we have SharePoint Server. As I said we use SharePoint Online, which is hosted by Microsoft. I'm going to assume that it includes SharePoint Server going by what you said, but I can't fully guarantee that. Thanks though!